# How do I remote invoke a windows command from a docker container?

Tags: docker, powershell

I need to remotely run a command on my window's workstation from my osx workstation using docker.

Works locally:

```
docker run -it  mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh -c "Write-Host 'Hello, World'"`
Hello, World
```

Doesn't work remote:

```
docker run -it  mcr.microsoft.com/powershell pwsh -c Invoke-Command -ComputerName VM-CHIP -ScriptBlock { Write-Host 'Hello, World' }
Invoke-Command: This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.
```

When I try within the container

```
docker run -it  mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
PowerShell 7.2.8
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /> Install-Module -Name PSWSMan

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): A
PS /> Install-WSMan                                                                                                     
WARNING: WSMan libs have been installed, please restart your PowerShell session to enable it in PowerShell
PS /> Invoke-Command -ComputerName VM-CHIP -ScriptBlock { Write-Host 'Hello, World' }
```

it fails with

```
OpenError: [VM-CHIP] Connecting to remote server VM-CHIP failed with the following error message : MI_RESULT_FAILED For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I'm confused what the structure is to run this within a single command intead of having to open interactive, and more importantly what am I missing to successfully execute the command on the remote machine instead of this `MI_RESULT_FAILED` error. Or is this not possible/supported?

Comment: Did you try doing as suggested, which is *see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic*?

Comment: I ended up pivoting and installing openssh server in windows. Now I can use ssh instead and works well for my use case.